# Make a public profile and a private profile in angular 4+

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli

I need help for think this problem, this is my firebase schema.

[image]

I need to make a view of the profile but public, how is the best way to make it?

So, what do you think about the schema and how does one user have conversations?

I think that the conversations node, can stay outside the user node and each referencing conversation to each user. Which one to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting multi data types under a single root, which is something most Firebase Realtime Database developers recommend against. Some of the most important reasons for this are:

1. Firebase will always read entire nodes, so you cannot read a user's properties without also reading all their conversations. There are many scenarios where this is wasteful, such as when you only want to show a list of user names.
2. Once you grant a user read access to a node, they have access to all data under that node. You cannot take this permission away at a lower level. This means in your case that anyone who can read a user's profile information, can also read all their conversations. This may not be what you want.
3. You may try to work around this last concern by giving the user read permission to the specific property of the users, so `/Users/$uid/name`, etc. that way they can read the names, but not the conversations. On a individual user node this will indeed work. But with this structure you cannot get a list of user profiles anymore, since you don't have read permission on `/Users`.

The common way to model what you shared is to split the conversations and the user profiles into separate top-level nodes, each keyed on the user's UID:

```
Users
  $uid
    name: "Matias Celiz"
    gender: "..."
Conversations
  $uid
    ...
```

If you want separate public profile information and private profile information, add another top-level node to split the two:

```
Users
  $uid
    name: "Matias Celiz"
    gender: "..."
Profiles
  $uid
    name: "Matias Celiz"
Conversations
  $uid
    ...
```